# AVR assembly language on Division

Tags: avr, assembly

how do i performs a division by 4 of the 16-bit unsigned value in registers r4:r5 Where r4 is the most significant  bit.

I understand that by division of 4 which means i have to shift the bit by 2. but how do i do it in assembly language? can i basically just LSL r4;LSLr5;? thank you for your help in explaining this.

Comment: Did you not learn from your previous two questions?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams still bit confusing in doing this, i understand how it works, but i am not confident how do i exactly put it in assembly language.

Comment: Why can't you simply _test_ it and see if you got it right?

Comment: Clear the carry bit, shift each byte right starting from the MSB, then do it twice.

Answer (score 2):

To divide by two:

**LSR r4** which push b0 to to carry b1 to b0, ... b7 to b6 and zero to b7

[image]

**ROR r5** which will push b0 to to carry b1 to b0, ... b7 to b6 and carry that is the b0 from r4 to b7

[image]

To divide by 4 use the sequence twice

LSL is used for multiplication.

The pictures are from Microchip Website [AVR Assembler Instructions](https://www.microchip.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_instruction_list.html)

Answer (score 2):

For example if the value is in the R24/R25 pair.

```
    lsr r25
    ror r24
    lsr r25
    ror r24
```

Answer (score 0):

Just divide by two, twice. Each divide by two is a right shift by one bit. Don't forget to clear the carry flag before shifting. Shifting twice can be done either in a loop or unrolled. In this case, unrolled may be more efficient.